# warning while using <Navigate> component of react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-navigation, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement `Navigate` in my code to redirect to another page when the submit button is clicked. Navigation happens but there are many errors on console.

ERROR:
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

[image]

```
import { Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
interface MyComponentState {
  navi: boolean;
}

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      navi: false,
    };
  }

submit = submit.bind(this);

render() {
  <div>
    <Component>
     <Button>
      onClick={this.submit}
     </Button>
    </Component>

   {this.state.navi && <Navigate to={`navigation/newpage`}/>}

  </div>

 }
}
```

```
import MyComponent from "../../MyComponent.tsx"
submit() {
  this.setState({
  navi: true,
  })
}
```

Comment: The initial `this.state.navi` value is true, so the `<Navigate to="navigation/newpage" />` is always rendered. Also, I don't know if this is just a copy/paste typo, but the button component's `onClick` handler isn't specified as a prop it seems. Also, are you trying to import a function with a `this.setState` call in it and bind the `this` of the `MyComponent` component to it? Why? Just declare the submit handler in the component. Can you fix the syntax issues and the image link?

Comment: this.state.navi has to be false by default(I wrote true by mistake while posting que)
Yes, I can define submit code there in the component itself, was following some code guidelines. 
My main concern is the Navigate component, and the error that it gives me.

Comment: That error appears to be something in a `MyApp` component. Are you sure this `Navigate` component has anything to do with the render looping? Can you post the actual error message and codestacktrace?

Comment: ERROR: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

This is the actual error message that I get on the console.
So, I checked that the render method is not looping by doing console.log
I am being redirected to the new url, but with this error message on the console.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?